# Ввод данных в MySQL через форму на php в одном файле

Tags: php, mysql

Вопрос такой: Есть таблица "customer" состоящая из двух полей "id_customer" и "name_customer", поле "id_customer" назначается автоматически. Необходимо через форму ввода записать данные в эту таблицу, но не после нажатия на кнопку "Сохранить", а после нажатия на ссылку "Сохранить". Все это должно быть в одном файле "add_customer.php" и каким образом должна выглядеть ссылка "Сохранить"?
Вот листинг файла "add_customer":

```
<?php
/*-- Подключение к БД и выбор таблицы --*/
require_once "maincore.php";

/*-- Запись данных в таблицу --*/
// Здесь должна быть функция записи

/*-- Форма ввода данных о заказчике --*/
echo "<form action='' method='POST' name='add_customer'>";
    echo "<table width='100%' align='center' valign='center'>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='right'>Заказчик:</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo "<input type='text' name='customer'>";
                echo "<br>";
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='right'>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<a href='#'>Сохранить</a>";
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

Comment: что за ужас? почему так много echo? Не проще чистым html вывести?

Comment: "Сохранить" должно быть не ссылкой! А <input type="sumbit"> или <button type="sumbit">Сохранить</button>

Comment: Можно хоть как главное чтобы в одном файле все былоэ

Comment: В том то и дело что кнопки быть не должно.

Comment: А возможно сделать как вы говорите, но что бы она не выглядела как кнопка. Например поставить картинку с галкой.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем столько эхо? Вывод текста, между прочим, тормозит работу php. Кстати, здесь можно вообще обойтись без php -

```
<form action='add.php' method='POST' name='add_customer'>
    <fieldset>
        <input type='text' name='customer'>
        <a href='#' onclick="form.submit();">Сохранить</a>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

На форму вешаем обработчик add.php, который будет забирать из нее данные (из массива $_POST[]) и отсылать запрос с добавлением в бд. На ссылку просто-напросто вешаем событие javascript '.submit()'.

Тут поподробнее learn.javascript.ru/forms-methods

Comment: А без JS никак? Например использовать вместо человеческой `<input type="submit">` использовать `<input type="image" src="your_image_url.png">` или css-ом декорировать обычную кнопку как угодно?

Comment: вывод текста тормозит работу php! калькуляции тормозят работу процессора! запросы тормозят работу сервера!

Comment: @Fike, дело в том что тут можно php вообще не дёргать, или дергать сильно меньше. Зачем совершать лишние телодвижения? Зачем писать десятки echo усложняющих чтение кода?

Comment: @MrClon, ну ТС же написал, что ему нужно повесить отправку формы именно на ссылку. В этом случае можно просто повесить на эту ссылку обработчик отправки.

Comment: честно говоря, смешно читать о том, что тормозит "эхо". Там такие незначительные тормоза, что наверное только фейсбук их может ощутить. 
Да и честно говоря я очень сомневаюсь, что чистый hmtl быстрее будет.
Самое главное: как обслуживать такой код? Вот тут да - нужно отделять шаблон от php. Т.к. потом сложно такую кашу поддерживать. 

P.S.Спорить не буду, но это было актуально в 90-х

Comment: @MrClon, 1) формально он все равно дернется - буферизация 2) я не про бездумное использование echo, а про конкретную фразу

Comment: @Req, а потом он написал что дело сугубо во внешнем виде

Answer (score 0):

Тэг `<a>` не умеет отправлять на сервер форы. Не для того он нужен. Если выбор требование использовать именно этот тэг продиктовано желание декорировать сабмитилку формы по своему желанию (а не, например, какими-то хитрыми религиозными соображениями) то спешу вас обрадовать — button тоже можно декорировать (присвоив ему класс и прописав для этого класса нужные атрибуты (первый попавшийся [пример](http://habrasorium.ru/css/573-bystryj-sposob-ukrasit-knopku.html))). Существует даже специальный тип инпута `[image][2]`, по поведению идентичный `button` но выглядящий как картинка.

Фронтэнд это только одна из составляющих задачи. Засабмичены кнопкой данные нужно ещё обработать на серверной части и записать в БД. при-этом следует помнить об SQL инъекциях. В php получить данные post-запроса можно и массива `$_POST`

Answer (score -2):

Можно попробовать с jQuery..

```
<a href='#' id="asumbit">Сохранить</a>
<script>
    $('#asumbit').on('click',function(){
        $('form[name=add_customer]').sumbit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: А как будет с кнопкой <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Сохранить'>

Comment: jQuery для <input type='submit'> не нужно. Инпут и так отправит форму

Comment: Я это понял, а как весь код выглядеть будет? И какая функция запись в базу произведет?

Comment: А без жабаскрипта уже и форму на сервер засабмитить нельзя?